# Control Telegram Bot via API (send message to bot programmatically)

Tags: telegram-bot, tasker

I have a raspberry pi at home with motion detection. I have set the PI up to send me alerts (and pictures) via a Telegram Bot. That all works fine.

I can also (manually) type into the chat, `"Home"` or `"Away"` to activate or deactivate the motion detection. I want to *automate* the sending of the  `"Home"` and `"Away"` messages (using `tasker`) when I leave/join my home wifi.

Short of making my own App, is there any way to hack this into place? I was playing around with trying to [set the chat description](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setchatdescription) and then query it, as a workaround, but I don't think that'll work for a private chat.

If there's a hack around, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cURL` command with HTTP API, you might need [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) or [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) method.

e.g. `curl "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=109780439&text=Away"`

Comment: That sends a message _from_ the bot right? I want to be able to send a message _to_ the bot (as if the user has typed on their keyboard).  The issue is that on the raspberry Pi, I want to be able to get the bot to do different things. If I use that command above ^ how would you then _query_ for that message (using `https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/getUpdates?offset=-1` or similar ?

Comment: Bot can't see another bots message, but you can use channel to do that.

Comment: Do you have an example? There isn't a `curl` command I can just use right?